# argument of type "PROCESSENTRY32W *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPPROCESSENTRY32"

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

Here is my code :

```
std::uint32_t find(const wchar_t* proc)
{
    auto snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    auto pe = PROCESSENTRY32W{ sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32W) };

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &pe)) {
        do {
            if (!_wcsicmp(proc, pe.szExeFile)) {
                CloseHandle(snapshot);
                return pe.th32ProcessID;
            }
        } while (Process32Next(snapshot, &pe));
    }
    CloseHandle(snapshot);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error **argument of type "PROCESSENTRY32W *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPPROCESSENTRY32"**. My Visual studio setting is set to use Multibyte character set. If I change it to unicode, it'll just break my whole project. What does this error mean and how can I fix my code?

Comment: Replace ``PROCESSENTRY32W `` (Wide character) with ``PROCESSENTRY32`` (Multibyte) then it will work

Comment: I replaced it like you said but now I'm getting : 

**'int _wcsicmp(const wchar_t *,const wchar_t *)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'CHAR [260]' to 'const wchar_t *'**

and : 

**argument of type "CHAR *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const wchar_t *"**

Comment: If your project is configured to use multibyte character encoding then you should replace ``wchar_t`` with ``char``. You should also use multibyte version of ``_wcsicmp``: ``_stricmp``

Comment: Thank you. Let me try it out and I will mark this as solve afterwards. Awesome :D

Comment: I have posted the solution below too. Hope it helps

Comment: Use Unicode. That's what your OS uses internally anyway. If it breaks your project, fix it once, and move forward from there. Using the ANSI versions of the Windows API introduces loads of issues. There are character strings, that cannot be represented using a single code page, and I'm not even sure, what this particular API returns in case a module name is one of those strings. Besides, it causes needless conversions whenever you call an API, or when it returns string data. The conversion also places arbitrary limits on string lengths, that are usually not even documented. Stop using ANSI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use multibyte version of `PROCESSENTRY32` structure instead of wide character:

```
std::uint32_t find(const char* proc)
{
    auto snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    auto pe = PROCESSENTRY32{ sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32) };

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &pe)) {
        do {
            if (!_stricmp(proc, pe.szExeFile)) {
                CloseHandle(snapshot);
                return pe.th32ProcessID;
            }
        } while (Process32Next(snapshot, &pe));
    }
    CloseHandle(snapshot);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: const char_t* gives an error. using just char gives no error, but I'll have to check if it'll actually work

Comment: Thanks for your help, it solved my Multibyte error and gave me a new one. I'm not sure if it's also a Multibyte error, however I Will mark this as solve.

Do you think you could help me out with this error in my other function? I think it's also a Unicode error but I'm not sure how to approach this one : https://pastebin.com/R6yArkyV

The error states : cannot convert from const char to std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_straights. Thank you for your help previously though!!!

Comment: Replace ``std::wstring`` with ``std::string``

Comment: Thank you!!!. No errors, it builds fine, but my code doesn't work so I guess it must be something else